# merge values in two rows in an sql table appear in two columns of one row

Tags: sql-server, merge

I need help in SQL. I have a table with this structure.

[image: this structure]:

What I need is a query to return the data like this.

[image: this]:

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,
bgergoe

Comment: conditional aggregation or pivot. research these and try them and then show us what you try if you fail.

Comment: Ah, the good old EAV anti-pattern, the bane of DBAs everywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been asked and answered dozens of times but it is super simple to write out the code. Conditional aggregation is pretty straight forward and the code is far less obtuse than PIVOT. Here is how you would go about this.

```
SELECT ID
    , MAX(CASE WHEN Field = 'name' THEN Value END) AS name
    , MAX(CASE WHEN Field = 'phone number' THEN Value END) AS PhoneNumber
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: You're awesome, thanks a lot for the prompt assistance, have a nice day!